# Regex in java - catch the dot

Tags: java, regex

How to add the dot to the last of regex and it's is the optional like:

public static final String REGEX_HASHTAGS = "([^|\s|>]*[a-z]{2}[0-9]+(\s|$|<)+)";

i want to catch the string like: cx10 or cx10.

Comment: Do you mean "dots"?  If so, the answer is `\.`, which you'd need to escape as `"\\."`

Comment: You mean dot, right? Also, `[^|\s|>]` doesn't do what you think it does. It will match any character which is not `|`, a space character or `>`

Comment: Yesss, sorry i mean is dot,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
public static final String REGEX_HASTAGS
    = "\\b[a-z]{2}[0-9]+\\.?\\b";
```

`\b` is the word anchor, and looks like what you want given your initial regex.

Comment: Thanks Keppil, it's OK for the dot but my regex only accept the "start string, space " in the first of input? and the "dot, space" at the end of string?
Plese help me to change your "\\b"

Comment: If you want a more detailed regex, you'll have to provide sample inputs where you want a match and inputs where you _do not_ want a match. I went for `\b` because it matched the intent in your question, but without samples it remains only a guess.

Comment: My regex apply for: "cx1000001" or " ca1987."
It's not apply for: "ccx1000001" or ".ca1987."

Comment: public static final String REGEX_HASHTAGS = "[^|\\s|>]*([a-z]{2}[0-9]+\\.?)\\b";

It's OK for me, thanks you all!!!! <3